# Wrapping program with TclApp causes smtp package to stop working properly?

Tags: tcl

So I'm getting a strange issue when trying to send an email from my company's local mail server using Tcl. The problem is I've written code that works, but it doesn't work as soon as I wrap it with TclApp. I believe I've included all the necessary packages.

Code:

```
package require smtp;
package require mime;
package require tls;

set body "Hello World, I am sending an email! Hear me roar.";

#mime info
set token [mime::initialize -canonical text/plain -string $body];

#mail options
set opts {};

#MAIL SERVER + PORT
lappend opts -servers "my_server";
lappend opts -ports 25;

tls::init -tls1 1;
lappend opts -username "someEmail@example.com";
lappend opts -password "somePasswordExample";

#SUBJECT + FROM + TO 
lappend opts -header [list "Subject" "This is a test e-mail, beware!!"];
lappend opts -header [list "From" "theFromEmail@example.com"];
lappend opts -header [list "To" "theToEmail@yahoo.com"]; 

if {[catch {
    smtp::sendmessage $token \
    {*}$opts \
    -queue false \
    -atleastone false \
    -usetls false \
    -debug 1;

    mime::finalize $token;

 } msg]} {
    set out [open "error_log.txt" w];
    puts $out $msg;
    close $out;
}

puts "Hit enter to continue...";
gets stdin;
exit;
```

This works when I run it and I successfully get the email sent. 
But when I wrap it, it doesn't. Here's the output after wrapping and executing the program: 
[image]

For whatever reason, wrapping with TclApp makes my program fail to authenticate.

*Update: I've decided to try to wrap the script with Freewrap to see if I get the same problem and amazingly I do not. Script works if not wrapped or if wrapped by Freewrap, but not TclApp; is this a bug in TclApp or am I simply missing something obvious?

It seems that this is an old problem (last post): https://community.activestate.com/forum/wrapping-package-tls151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I've found the solution to my problem and solved it! Hopefully this answer will help anyone else who ran into the same issue.

---

I contacted ActiveState and they were able to point me in the right direction - [this](https://community.activestate.com/forum/my-application-no-longer-works-after-being-wrapped#comment-12710) link to a thread on the ActiveState forums goes over a similar issue.

I've decided to run the prefix file I've been using to wrap my programs in TclApp - I am using `base-tk8.6-thread-win32-ix86`. Running this opens up a console/Tcl interpreter which allowed me to try sourcing my Tcl e-mail script manually and I found that *the prefix file/interpreter by itself was completely unaware of the location of any package on my system* and that I needed to lappend to the auto_path the location of the packages I wanted. Moreover I found from the thread that the email script I was using required other dependencies I had not wrapped in. Namely `sha1, SASL, and otp` among their own dependencies. When I got these dependencies my script worked through the base-tk8.6-thread-win32-ix86 interpreter and subsequantly through my wrapped program.

Another clue that these dependencies were necessary after doing some research was that my script would give me a `530: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.`  I later learned SASL fixed this - but I don't know anything about networking so I wouldn't have guessed it.

The other thing I learned was there is a distinct difference between `teacup get` and `teacup install` which is why I wasn't installing Tcl packages correctly and TclApp was unaware of SASL, sha1, or otp.

What I don't understand, and perhaps someone with more in depth knowledge about these programs can tell me, how does Wish86 know about a script's package dependencies and know where to find them?? It wasn't until I tried looking for the packages in TclApp that I realized I didn't even have sha1, SASL, etc. on my system nor did I included their `package require` commands at the top of my script, yet Wish86 could execute my script perfectly. The frustrating thing about this is it is difficult to know whether or not you've met all dependency requirements for systems that don't have a magical Wish86 interpreter that just makes everything work (lol.)

After looking through the end of the thread, I found there is a discussion on the depth TclApp goes to look for hard and soft dependencies in projects.

---

EDIT: Added more information.

Comment: You can also add the required libraries under `lib/`, which is in the auto-path. Depending on the library, you might have to write the appropriate `pkgIndex.tcl` files yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Investigate whether the wrapped version has the same .dll
   dependencies as in the article you linked.
2. Check in the TCL Wiki to see whether this is a known issue ( [TCL
   Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3960) ).
3. Are you initializing your environment properly when wrapped ( [TCL
   App Initialization](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.6/tcl/TclLib/AppInit.htm) )?